# mySQL create table script with output

Tags: mysql

What I am currently looking to do is write a script where I use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statements to create missing tables. How exactly could I go about adding in some sort of output to the user who is using this script? It is essentially a long line of create table statements and I would like it to print out something like "this_table was added" at the end of the script. I want to output something for the tables that are not found, and are created.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`user_group` (
`key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`version` int(11) NOT NULL,
`display_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`color` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) ENGINE=genericDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I don't have MySQL available right now, so I can't test it, but can you use    SELECT ROW_COUNT() after a DDL?

Comment: @Joel would that not execute regardless of whether or not it creates the table?

Comment: I think the value it returns will be different whether or not the table was created or not....  Store the results in a variable and check the value of the variable, then reset back to 0.  Sorry I'm connected to MySQL right not to code and test, but I'm trying to help anyway.

Comment: Well you can select from the information schema and check whether tha table was created or not and print the result. See it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: @Joel I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jorge Campos I can look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a delimiter to run two queries together

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create table Y(id int primary key)//select "Y Created";//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

+-----------+
| Y Created |
+-----------+
| Y Created |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```